# Bootstrap v 3.2 Component Display (Collapsing Horizontal Panel)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'd like to create a fixed top navbar by taking the mobile-first design approach and using BS v 3.2. I'm also using 'less' as a pre-compiler.

As such I've built a navbar that looks something like this in html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- And below is the dropdown menu toggle button which displays all elements visible in the non-collapsed version of the navbar-->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
...
</nav>
```

The above works correctly.

Where I'm getting stuck however is that in the mobile view, when a user clicks the above toggle button, I'd like for two things to happen:

1) The drop down menu under the toggle button will no longer appear (and I've figured this part out easily enough).

2) The content that was in that drop down menu will instead appear in a panel which slides onto the device display from the left, pushing ALL other content to the right. This is the tricky part for me.

I suspect it would take a good deal of effort to re-code Bootstrap's javascript in order to implement the desired behavior, and therefore I'm curious if using collapse.js on a panel element would possibly be a suitable alternative? I've already figured out how to make the panel collapse horizontally instead of vertically (html below):

```
<div id="panel1" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse width">
        <div class="panel-body" style="width: 400px;">
        Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I'm stuck now is that the menu content is displayed `block`; i.e. first it pushes all other content down and then it slides in / un-collapses across the top of the display. I would like for it to push existing content off the right edge of the screen.

Is it possible to achieve an inline display? I know BS is particular about container - row - column, and I've tried to put two containers next to each other to make this work, but no luck. It's very possible I'm doing something incorrectly.

Also, if the panel isn't the best solution, I'm definitely open to others. Please help!!!

And let me know if I can clarify anything.

Cheers,

Comment: Try googling for Bootstrap Offcanvas, Bootstrap slidein menu, bootstrap push menu. http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/
http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/seqola/1/edit

Comment: http://exisweb.net/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns -- bootstrap is css and js, you can add  other jQuery and CSS to it. There's an icon-bar push menu I've seen but I can't find it.

Comment: @Christina: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am going to use Jasny Bootstrap (http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/) and the Off Canvas javascript component since it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasny Bootstrap provides the above functionality. Check it out at: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/components.

The 'Off Canvas' component is the one I wanted.

Cheers.

Edit: At Harry's request (below), here is sample code using the Jasny Bootstrap component. You will still however need to incorporate its libraries into your project.

```
<nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">
...
</nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```